# Figuring out the time until midnight, and output the result in a text file

Tags: shell, freebsd

How could I make lets say remaining time until tomorrow (midnight, also hours and minutes) and save that to a text file, like for example, "x hours and y minutes remaining until midnight"

Sry for being a noob. :(

Comment: Hi! No need to apologize for being a newb. But: why are you tagging this with [tag:Cron]? What does it have to do with it? Do you need to call it from a Cron script? If so, why?(as that should be aware of the time, anyways)

Comment: Also, why the conflicting operating system tags?

Comment: @MarcusMüller the questions was originally about cron,if It would be possible to figure out the time remaining until next cron job, but some say that just isn't possible. My cron job runs daily, so we could just calculate the time remaining from now to until midnight and output that to a text file. And also sorry for the conflicting tags, I just forgot to fix it all up after editing.

Comment: Hm, what do you need that for? This really seems like you're solving something potentially simple through something slightly convoluted... what's the purpose of writing that to a file? I can't really find a use case for that, because whatever reads that for could do the calculation just as well

Comment: @MarcusMüllerI I wanted to make something cool for my game server, basically I am using cron for generating a new world map daily automatically, and I wanted the motd of the server to say the time remaining until next reset. So that's why I wanted to calculate the time until midnight from now and output it into the servers motd file. All I need help for is just getting it to output the time in hours and minutes to a text file and I can work from there.

Comment: So um I don't know which game server you're running, but this sounds more like something you'd write as script in the scripting language of said server, so that it just gives the right answer whenever someone connects, instead of continuously overwriting a file, hoping to never happen upon a situation where the server reads while you write...

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's a terraria server (running tshock) If I get the time calculated and output the hours and minutes to a file, I can work by myself from there (create another cron job for that updates the motd every minute running another shell script). If you know how to help, please.

Comment: Don't. Script this on terraria server, not around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to apologize for asking questions; we're here to help! To calculate the remaining time until midnight and save it to a text file in the format "x hours and y minutes remaining until midnight," you can use a scripting language like Python. Here's a simple Python script to do that:

```py
import datetime

# Get the current time
now = datetime.datetime.now()

# Calculate the time until midnight
midnight = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
time_until_midnight = midnight - now

# Extract hours and minutes
hours, seconds = divmod(time_until_midnight.seconds, 3600)
minutes = seconds // 60

# Format the message
remaining_time_message = f"{hours} hours and {minutes} minutes remaining until midnight"

# Save the message to a text file
with open("remaining_time.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(remaining_time_message)

print(remaining_time_message)
```

Here's how the script works:

1. It imports the `datetime` module to work with date and time values.
2. It gets the current time using `datetime.datetime.now()`.
3. It calculates the time until midnight by creating a `datetime` object for midnight and subtracting the current time.
4. It extracts the hours and minutes from the time difference.
5. It formats the message using an f-string.
6. It saves the message to a text file named "remaining_time.txt" using a `with` statement.

When you run this script, it will calculate the remaining time until midnight and save the message to the specified text file. You can then read the content of "remaining_time.txt" to see the result.

To execute the script, save it to a .py file (e.g., `calculate_remaining_time.py`) and run it using a Python interpreter:

```
python calculate_remaining_time.py
```

The script will print the message to the console and save it to "remaining_time.txt."

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the time left until midnight using this for example (assuming GNU `date`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash -
mid=$(date -d 'tomorrow 00:00' +%s)
now=$(date +%s)
hours=$(((mid - now) / 3600))
mins=$(((mid - now - hours * 3600) / 60))
printf "%d hours and %d minutes remaining until midnight\n" "$hours" "$mins"
```

With FreeBSD `date`, use this instead to calculate `mid`:

```bash
mid=$(date -v+1d -v0H -v0M -v0S +%s)
```

On Linux, if you don’t mind losing the minutes, you can use `systemd-analyze calendar`; this can be adapted to address your original question, by changing the argument to reflect the schedule of a cron job:

```
$ systemd-analyze calendar '*-*-* 0:0:0' | grep "From now"
       From now: 15h left
```

Comment: if using `systemd-analyze calendar daily` , remaining minutes will appear when less than some (5 ?) hour left.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
$ date +%H:%M | { IFS=: read h m; t=$((1440-60*h-m)); printf 'Time is %s:%s, %sh %sm until midnight\n' "$h" "$m" "$((t/60))" "$((t%60))"; }
Time is 11:38, 12h 22m until midnight
```

This reads the `HH:MM`-formatted time from `date` and converts it into the number of minutes left of the day.  This is `t`.

It then outputs the number of hours and minutes this `t` value adds up to.

Pretty-printed version of the pipeline:

```bash
date +%H:%M | {
    IFS=: read h m
    t=$(( 1440 - 60*h - m ))
    printf 'Time is %s:%s, %sh %sm until midnight\n' "$h" "$m" "$(( t/60 ))" "$(( t%60 ))"
}
```

Note that this may show the wrong result in the early hours of days when daylight-saving switches occur.  The relative simplicity of the code arguably makes up for that.

---

The same thing, but taking seconds into account as well, which means `t` will now be the remaining number of seconds until midnight.

```bash
date +%H:%M:%S | {
    IFS=: read h m s
    t=$(( 86400 - 3600*h - 60*m - s ))
    printf 'Time is %s:%s:%s, %sh %sm %ss until midnight\n' \
        "$h" "$m" "$s" "$(( t/3600 ))" "$(( (t%3600)/60 ))" "$(( (t%3600)%60 ))"
}
```